How to create a valid signed message and obtain v, r, s for EIP-712 verification in Solidity?
I'm working on a Solidity smart contract that involves EIP-712 signing and message verification. The contract defines a DOMAIN_SEPARATOR and includes a function to hash and verify an HTLC struct.
Here is the contract code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.23;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";

struct EIP712Domain {
    string name;
    string version;
    uint256 chainId;
    address verifyingContract;
    bytes32 salt;
}

struct HTLC {
    string dstAddress;
    string dstChain;
    string dstAsset;
    string srcAsset;
    address payable sender;
    address payable srcReceiver;
    bytes32 hashlock;
    uint256 secret;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 timelock;
    bool redeemed;
    bool unlocked;
}

contract HashedTimeLockEther {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;
    using Address for address;

    bytes32 private DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;
    bytes32 private constant SALT = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("hello"));

    constructor() {
        DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = hashDomain(
            EIP712Domain({
                name: "HashedTimeLockEther",
                version: "1",
                chainId: block.chainid,
                verifyingContract: address(this),
                salt: SALT
            })
        );
    }

    function hashDomain(EIP712Domain memory domain) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256(
                    "EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract,bytes32 salt)"
                ),
                keccak256(bytes(domain.name)),
                keccak256(bytes(domain.version)),
                domain.chainId,
                domain.verifyingContract,
                domain.salt
            )
        );
    }

    function hashMessage(HTLC memory message) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256(
                    "HTLC(string dstAddress,string dstChain,string dstAsset,string srcAsset,address payable sender,address payable srcReceiver,bytes32 hashlock,uint256 secret,uint256 amount,uint256 timelock,bool redeemed,bool unlocked)"
                ),
                keccak256(bytes(message.dstAddress)),
                keccak256(bytes(message.dstChain)),
                keccak256(bytes(message.dstAsset)),
                keccak256(bytes(message.srcAsset)),
                message.sender,
                message.srcReceiver,
                message.hashlock,
                message.secret,
                message.amount,
                message.timelock,
                message.redeemed,
                message.unlocked
            )
        );
    }

    function verifyMessage(HTLC memory message, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", DOMAIN_SEPARATOR, hashMessage(message)));

        address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);

        return (recoveredAddress == message.sender);
    }
}

Here's the script in JS, that I'm using to generate the signature:
const ethers = require("ethers");

async function signHTLC() {
    const domain = {
        name: "HashedTimeLockEther",
        version: "1",
        chainId: 11155111,
        verifyingContract: "0xC234Baf9e5f63979d4bAC63127CE4127D3E3638E",
        salt: "0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8"
    };

    // Use ethers.js to encode the domain and compute the domain separator
    const domainSeparator = ethers.keccak256(
        ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode(
            ['bytes32', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'uint256', 'address', 'bytes32'],
            [
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract,bytes32 salt)')),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(domain.name)),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(domain.version)),
                domain.chainId,
                domain.verifyingContract,
                domain.salt
            ]
        )
    );

    console.log('Computed Domain Separator:', domainSeparator);

    const types = {
        HTLC: [
            { name: "dstAddress", type: "string" },
            { name: "dstChain", type: "string" },
            { name: "dstAsset", type: "string" },
            { name: "srcAsset", type: "string" },
            { name: "sender", type: "address" },
            { name: "srcReceiver", type: "address" },
            { name: "hashlock", type: "bytes32" },
            { name: "secret", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "amount", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "timelock", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "redeemed", type: "bool" },
            { name: "unlocked", type: "bool" },
        ],
    };

    const message = {
        dstAddress: "0xRecipientAddressHere",
        dstChain: "Ethereum",
        dstAsset: "ETH",
        srcAsset: "BTC",
        sender: "0xF6517026847B4c166AAA176fe0C5baD1A245778D",
        srcReceiver: "0xF6517026847B4c166AAA176fe0C5baD1A245778D",
        hashlock: "0x7365646667000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        secret: 123456789,
        amount: 1000000000,
        timelock: 1699999999,
        redeemed: false,
        unlocked: false,
    };

    const privateKey = "0xe9ac8db510ad074c275c8cff89e9.....";
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);

    const signature = await wallet.signTypedData(domain, types, message);
    console.log("Signature:", signature);

    const sig = ethers.Signature.from(signature);
    console.log({
        r: sig.r,
        s: sig.s,
        v: sig.v
    });
}

signHTLC().catch(console.error);

Basically, I'm trying to create a valid signed message and obtain the v, r, s components to pass as the params to the verifyMessage function for verification. How should I go about generating these values? Specifically, what would be the process to sign the HTLC struct data correctly and extract the v, r, s components?
Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

@syed-asad-kazmi could you please check this ?

Sure. You want a script to generate the signature, JS or Python?

@syed-asad-kazmi i want in js. I have created one,but unfortunately it doesnt pass

@syed-asad-kazmi the problem is I need also  r v and s as those are the parameters which i should pass to verification function

Okay. I would be able to try that within a few hours, as my Wifi connection is not there. Meanwhile, you can refer to this answer, as it might help.

@syed-asad-kazmi  thanks a lot,while waiting for your help i will try to investigate that answer.Thanks once more

Can you add the script that you’re trying, in your question?

Yes I will add now

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@syed-asad-kazmi have you been able to check ?

Use some ready script, for example https://github.com/Mrtenz/eip-712 . Haven't tried that one myself, but looks ok. Or just google for more options.

@lauri-peltonen based on that code i have created mine for my project but it fails on sepolia testnet

@syed-asad-kazmi are you here ?

First of all, as mentioned in this answer, you should use the \x19Ethereum Signed Message prefix while recovering the signer of a signed message in Solidity.
So, in the verifyMessage() function of your contract, replace:
address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);

with:
address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(
    keccak256(
        abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", digest)
    ),
    v,
    r,
    s
);

But still, the signature generated by wallet.signTypedData() of ethers.js is not getting validated. I think there might be some discrepancy in the generation/validation of signature specifically in case of signTypedData function, and that's something I'm willing to explore further and will leave it to others to answer the reason behind that discrepancy.
So, a workaround would be to use the wallet.signMessage() to sign the digest of the typed data.
For doing that, we need to:

generate the hash of the abi-encoded message,
use the message hash to generate the abi-encoded typed data, and
hash the abi-encoded typed data to get the digest.

Here's the revised script, i.e., using the wallet.signMessage() function to generate the signature:
const ethers = require("ethers");
require("dotenv").config();

async function signHTLC() {
    const domain = {
        name: "HashedTimeLockEther",
        version: "1",
        chainId: 11155111,
        verifyingContract: process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        salt: "0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8"
    };

    // Use ethers.js to encode the domain and compute the domain separator
    const domainSeparator = ethers.keccak256(
        ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode(
            ['bytes32', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'uint256', 'address', 'bytes32'],
            [
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract,bytes32 salt)')),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(domain.name)),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(domain.version)),
                domain.chainId,
                domain.verifyingContract,
                domain.salt
            ]
        )
    );

    console.log('Computed Domain Separator:', domainSeparator);

    const types = {
        HTLC: [
            { name: "dstAddress", type: "string" },
            { name: "dstChain", type: "string" },
            { name: "dstAsset", type: "string" },
            { name: "srcAsset", type: "string" },
            { name: "sender", type: "address" },
            { name: "srcReceiver", type: "address" },
            { name: "hashlock", type: "bytes32" },
            { name: "secret", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "amount", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "timelock", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "redeemed", type: "bool" },
            { name: "unlocked", type: "bool" },
        ],
    };

    const message = {
        dstAddress: process.env.RECIPIENT_ADDRESS,
        dstChain: "Ethereum",
        dstAsset: "ETH",
        srcAsset: "BTC",
        sender: process.env.SENDER_ADDRESS,
        srcReceiver: "0xF6517026847B4c166AAA176fe0C5baD1A245778D",
        hashlock: "0x7365646667000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        secret: 123456789,
        amount: 1000000000,
        timelock: 1699999999,
        redeemed: false,
        unlocked: false,
    };

    const messageHash = ethers.keccak256(
        ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode(
            ['bytes32', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'address', 'address', 'bytes32', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'bool', 'bool'],
            [
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes('HTLC(string dstAddress,string dstChain,string dstAsset,string srcAsset,address payable sender,address payable srcReceiver,bytes32 hashlock,uint256 secret,uint256 amount,uint256 timelock,bool redeemed,bool unlocked)')),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(message.dstAddress)),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(message.dstChain)),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(message.dstAsset)),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(message.srcAsset)),
                message.sender, // address
                message.srcReceiver, // address
                message.hashlock, // bytes32
                message.secret, // uint256
                message.amount, // uint256
                message.timelock, // uint256
                message.redeemed, // bool
                message.unlocked  // bool
            ]
        )
    );

    console.log('Hashed message:', messageHash);

    const digest = ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256(
        ["bytes2", "bytes32", "bytes32"],
        [
            ethers.toUtf8Bytes("\x19\x01"),
            domainSeparator,
            messageHash
        ]
    );

    const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);

    console.log("Digest:", digest);

    const signature = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.getBytes(digest));

    console.log("Signature:", signature);

    const sig = ethers.Signature.from(signature);
    console.log({
        r: sig.r,
        s: sig.s,
        v: sig.v
    });
}

signHTLC().catch(console.error);

OUTPUT

And, the v, r, s of the generated signature can be verified correctly:


Edit: As CT95 has mentioned in his answer, removing the payable from the address type fields of the HTLC struct in the contract, thereby removing the payable while abi-encoding the HTLC struct in the hashMessage() function as well, results in the successful validation of the signature generated by wallet.signTypedData().
NOTE: You don't need to add \x19Ethereum Signed Message prefix in this case.
So, the revised contract would be:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.23;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol";

struct EIP712Domain {
    string name;
    string version;
    uint256 chainId;
    address verifyingContract;
    bytes32 salt;
}

struct HTLC {
    string dstAddress;
    string dstChain;
    string dstAsset;
    string srcAsset;
    address sender;
    address srcReceiver;
    bytes32 hashlock;
    uint256 secret;
    uint256 amount;
    uint256 timelock;
    bool redeemed;
    bool unlocked;
}

contract HashedTimeLockEther {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;
    using Address for address;

    bytes32 private DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;
    bytes32 private constant SALT = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("hello"));

    constructor() {
        DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = hashDomain(
            EIP712Domain({
                name: "HashedTimeLockEther",
                version: "1",
                chainId: block.chainid,
                verifyingContract: address(this),
                salt: SALT
            })
        );
    }

    function hashDomain(EIP712Domain memory domain) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256(
                    "EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract,bytes32 salt)"
                ),
                keccak256(bytes(domain.name)),
                keccak256(bytes(domain.version)),
                domain.chainId,
                domain.verifyingContract,
                domain.salt
            )
        );
    }

    function hashMessage(HTLC memory message) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256(
                    "HTLC(string dstAddress,string dstChain,string dstAsset,string srcAsset,address sender,address srcReceiver,bytes32 hashlock,uint256 secret,uint256 amount,uint256 timelock,bool redeemed,bool unlocked)"
                ),
                keccak256(bytes(message.dstAddress)),
                keccak256(bytes(message.dstChain)),
                keccak256(bytes(message.dstAsset)),
                keccak256(bytes(message.srcAsset)),
                message.sender,
                message.srcReceiver,
                message.hashlock,
                message.secret,
                message.amount,
                message.timelock,
                message.redeemed,
                message.unlocked
            )
        );
    }

    function verifyMessage(HTLC memory message, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", DOMAIN_SEPARATOR, hashMessage(message)));

        address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);

        return (recoveredAddress == message.sender);
    }
}

Now, you can retain your original script as it is:
const ethers = require("ethers");
require("dotenv").config();

async function signHTLC() {
    const domain = {
        name: "HashedTimeLockEther",
        version: "1",
        chainId: 11155111,
        verifyingContract: process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        salt: "0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8"
    };

    // Use ethers.js to encode the domain and compute the domain separator
    const domainSeparator = ethers.keccak256(
        ethers.AbiCoder.defaultAbiCoder().encode(
            ['bytes32', 'bytes32', 'bytes32', 'uint256', 'address', 'bytes32'],
            [
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract,bytes32 salt)')),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(domain.name)),
                ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(domain.version)),
                domain.chainId,
                domain.verifyingContract,
                domain.salt
            ]
        )
    );

    console.log('Computed Domain Separator:', domainSeparator);

    const types = {
        HTLC: [
            { name: "dstAddress", type: "string" },
            { name: "dstChain", type: "string" },
            { name: "dstAsset", type: "string" },
            { name: "srcAsset", type: "string" },
            { name: "sender", type: "address" },
            { name: "srcReceiver", type: "address" },
            { name: "hashlock", type: "bytes32" },
            { name: "secret", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "amount", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "timelock", type: "uint256" },
            { name: "redeemed", type: "bool" },
            { name: "unlocked", type: "bool" },
        ],
    };

    const message = {
        dstAddress: process.env.RECIPIENT_ADDRESS,
        dstChain: "Ethereum",
        dstAsset: "ETH",
        srcAsset: "BTC",
        sender: process.env.SENDER_ADDRESS,
        srcReceiver: "0xF6517026847B4c166AAA176fe0C5baD1A245778D",
        hashlock: "0x7365646667000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        secret: 123456789,
        amount: 1000000000,
        timelock: 1699999999,
        redeemed: false,
        unlocked: false,
    };

    const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);

    const signature = await wallet.signTypedData(domain, types, message);

    console.log("Signature:", signature);

    const sig = ethers.Signature.from(signature);
    console.log({
        r: sig.r,
        s: sig.s,
        v: sig.v
    });
}

signHTLC().catch(console.error);


Your problem can be solved if you change address payable sender,address payable srcReceiver -> address sender,address srcReceiver.
In sign typed data, we don't distinguish address is payable or not.
